# How to get the item to be discarded in python deque?

Tags: python, deque

Suppose we have a `deque` with `maxlen=3`. If the `deque` already have 3 items and when I `append` a new item, how can I get the item that's going to be discarded?

The reason is that I want to maintain a window in memory that only contains the last N item, and when the window is full and one item is to be discarded, I need to get that item and do some extra work.

Here's my current solution:

```
from collection import deque

MAX_LEN=10

q = deque(maxlen=MAX_LEN)

while True:
    if len(q) == MAX_LEN:
        discarded = q.popleft()
        process(discarded)
    q.append(some_var)
```

Is this the best I can get? I've thought of using `list` and slice the list to limit size/get discarded item, but the `if` is unavoidable. Using `deque` at least I can get `O(1)` performance in the `push` and `popleft` operation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not `process(q[0]); q.append(some_var)`?

Comment: @Bakuriu I need to process the one that's to be discarded. So the queue starts with 0 item, and when it reaches 3 item, I need to start processing `q[0]`. I just want to avoid the `if` comparison in the loop.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, nor do I think you can do it any better. Although you *can* get rid of the `discarded` variable. And you *could* create a new subclass to do this for you

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve here? There's no way the length test has a significant impact on performance, so what do you have to gain by trying to optimize it away? Besides, one way or another, you *must* check if you're at the maximum length, so the most I think you can do is `process(q.popleft())` without the interim variable binding to `discarded`.

Comment: The `deque` is the right data structure (in terms of efficiency), but it doesn't provide a "built-in" way of achieving what you want (which basically is a callback to be used in conjunction with `maxlen`...). The only way to avoid the explicit `if` is to hide it into some code that could be a subclass or (IMHO better) a simple wrapper of the `deque`.

Comment: I think one would like leave the discarding to the deque, that's its job, but have a way of retrieving discarded elements anyway. This code, while functional, feels more like a hack on deque than a real solution.

Comment: @njzk2 You are right. In fact the above code would work as well without using `maxlen` at all.

Comment: @Bakuriu : exactly. all that testing and poping items is really what a deque does. It feels frustrating to re-write it.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Can you show an example of a simpler queue? AFAIK `deque` *is* the simplest and fastest queue the stdlib provides. Note that the `queue` module provides *synchronized* queues, which are only useful when using multi-threading.

Comment: @Bakuriu yes, actually you are right.

Comment: Is your maxlen really only 3? If it is... just make your own. It'll probably be faster too. Or was that just "for example"?

Comment: If you can fit the generation of new values into a generator. You could create a dequee or tee based generator holding a 3 wide sized window of the iteration. Then you could read the first element of each yield, instead of pop and append each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The intended way to get the item about to be discarded is with indexed lookup: `[0]`:

```
>>> from collections import deque

>>> d = deque('abc', maxlen=3)
>>> about_to_be_discarded = d[0]
>>> about_to_be_discarded
'a'
>>> d.append('d')
>>> d
deque(['b', 'c', 'd'], maxlen=3)
```

The secondary problem is avoiding an `if` to determine whether the deque is full.  One approach is to have two separate loops, one that initially fills the window and another that handles discards as new values are loaded:

```
d = deque(maxlen=n)
for i in range(n):
    d.append(get_input_value())
while True:
    discard = d[0]
    d.append(get_input_value())
    process(discard)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you.

```
def pairwise(iterable, n=2 ):
    from itertools import tee, islice, izip
    return izip(*(islice(it,pos,None) for pos,it in enumerate(tee(iterable, n))))


for values in pairwise(infinite_iterable_generating_your_values, n=3):
    process(values[0])
    if breakconditions:
        break
```

example of the pairwise function:

```
print [i for i in pairwise(range(10), n=3)]

[(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9)]
```